# Last column of multicols spreads more than the others (exam parts)

Tags: spacing, multicol, exam, parts

I'm generating [math worksheets](http://ruscalatex.eu.pythonanywhere.com/) with LaTeX (PyLaTeX), with the Exam document type.

I found that the last column of the multicols often has a lot more vertical whitespace than the others (to the point where sometimes less items fit in the page and I end up with items that should fit bleeding to the next page because of that).

I'm using parts with multicols, which end up like this:

```
\question[60]%
Question title%
\begin{parts}%
\begin{multicols}{3}%
\part%
$some math$%
\vspace{0.5cm}%
...
\end{multicols}%
\end{parts}%
```

And you can see the issue here (there are 7 parts per column):

[image: Weird behaviour in last column]

Anyone knows what could be causing it? It happens through all the web app and makes it quite harder to choose quantities, since most of the time I can't rely on them being multiples of the number of columns.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: multicol has various parameters to control that (what is needed really depends on the application (the defult is mainlyfor normal running text), so try `texdoc multicol`